# Touchpad not working in HP Pavilion 14 Notebook with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, touchpad, hp

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop and it's wonderful, but the only problem is my touchpad. It is not as sensitive as it should be and clicking with it instead of using the button only works sometimes. I'm new to Ubuntu, so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install "gpointing-device-settings", a graphical utility to set  touchpad parameters:
Run this command to install:
`sudo apt-get install gsynaptics`

Then launch the program with this command in a terminal: (possibly the installer made an icon in Unity system settings)
`gpointing-device-settings`
You will see interesting settings in "tapping" tab .

[image: *enter image description here*]

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem years ago (Sorry for not accepting your answer before, but I just noticed).